# pyspark-python3 _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

- Python Version : 3.6.5
- Spark : 2.3.0

Testing a udf which takes input `<class 'pyspark.sql.column.Column'>` of type and when I print it, it has `Column<b' with bytecodes  ...`

```
udf_call = udf(udf_funct, StringType())
col_columns = [col(c) for c in df.columns]
print(col_columns) 
#has list with bytecodes Column<b' which is not in case of 2.7
udf_call(struct(*col_columns))
```

**error**

> TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
>      During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: 
>      File "/*/*/*/SPARK2-2.3.0.*-1.*.*/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py",
>   line 918, in dumps
>       cp.dump(obj)
>       File "/*/*/*/SPARK2-2.3.0.*/lib/spark2/python/pyspark/cloudpickle.py", line
>   249, in dump
>       raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)
>       _pickle.PicklingError: Could not serialize object: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Comment: what is `udf_funct`?

Comment: ```pyspark udf udf_funct which takes 'pyspark.sql.column.Column' argument   Column<b'named_struct(NamePlaceholder(), column1, NamePlaceholder(), column2, NamePlaceholder(), column3, NamePlaceholder(), NamePlaceholder(), col4)'>
while running in 2.7 only difference is b' in the begginning ```

Comment: Can you post a sample of your input df, relevant code which calls your udf and expected output?

Comment: https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/797
``` similar to this issue i am running on local mode but still it gives the error similar to the error in the link```

Comment: ```
1. My project has sub packages and then a sub package
pkg
   subpckg1
          subpkg2
                .py
2. from my Main.py im calling a UDF which will be calling a function in subpkg2(.py) file
3 .due to more nesting functions and inter communication UDF's with lot other functions some how spark job couldn't find the subpkg2 files

solution :
@SchwarzeHuhn  create a egg file of the pkg and send via --py-files.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59741832/pyspark-custom-udf-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. My project has sub packages and then a sub package
   pkg
   subpckg1
         subpkg2
               .py
2. from my Main.py im calling a UDF which will be calling a function in subpkg2(.py) file
   3 .due to more nesting functions and inter communication UDF's with lot other functions some how spark job couldn't find the subpkg2 files

solution :
create a egg file of the pkg and send via --py-files.